# How would you query an array of 1's and 0's chars from a database?

Tags: database, arrays, bitvector

Say you had a long array of chars that are either 1 or 0, kind of like a bitvector, but on a database column. How would you query to know what values are set/no set? Say you need to know if the char 500 and char 1500 are "true" or not.

Comment: Are 500 and 1500 just arbitrary positions or do you query exactly those two again and again?

Comment: Totally arbitrary, the query could be something horrible like 500,551,1502,234,1001,2035 for example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT
  Id
FROM
  BitVectorTable
WHERE
  SUBSTRING(BitVector, 500, 1) = '1'
  AND SUBSTRING(BitVector, 1000, 1) = '1'
```

No index can be used for this kind of query, though. When you have many rows, this will get slow very quickly.

Edit: On SQL Server at least, all built-in string functions are [deterministic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx). That means you could look into the possibility to make computed columns based on the SUBSTRING() results for the whole combined value, [putting an index on each of them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx). Inserts will be slower, table size will increase, but searches will be really fast.

```
SELECT
  Id
FROM
  BitVectorTable
WHERE
  BitVector_0500 = '1'
  AND BitVector_1000 = '1'
```

Edit #2: The [limits for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx) are:

- 1,024 columns per normal table
- 30.000 columns per "wide" table

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL, something using [substring](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) like

```
select foo from bar 
where substring(col, 500,1)='1' and substring(col, 1500,1)='1';
```

This will be pretty inefficient though, you might want to rethink your schema. For example, you could store each bit separately to tradeoff space for speed...

```
create table foo
(
   id int not null,
   bar varchar(128),
   primary key(id)
);

create table foobit
(
   int foo_id int not null,
   int idx int not null,
   value tinyint not null,

   primary key(foo_id,idx),
   index(idx,value)
);
```

Which would be queried

```
   select foo.bar from foo
   inner join foobit as bit500
      on(foo.id=bit500.foo_id and bit500.idx=500)
   inner join foobit as bit1500
      on(foo.id=bit1500.foo_id and bit1500.idx=1500)
   where
      bit500.value=1 and bit1500.value=1;
```

Obviously consumes more storage, but should be faster for those query operations as an index will be used.

Answer (score 2):

I would convert the column to multiple bit-columns and rewrite the relevant code - Bit masks are so much faster than string comparisons. But if you can't do that, you must use db-specific functions. Regular expressions could be an option

```
-- Flavor: MySql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP "^.{499}1.{999}1"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select substring(your_col, 500,1) as char500,
substring(your_col, 1500,1) as char1500 from your_table;
```